# Loki db changes new project integration

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, lokijs

My project new integration  :

I am using `find()` method but it is not working.

```
var arrayResults = collection.find({'userId':$rootScope.userId,'productType':'kcc'});
```

Like this working fine.

```
var arrayResults = collection.find({'productType':'kcc'});
```

am looking like this please help me any one.
var arrayResults = collection.find({'userId':$rootScope.userId,'productType':'kcc'});

Answer (score 0):

Given only this information without a code sample, I would say this won't work because $rootScope isn't defined in that controller or etc.
Try to logout the $rootScope.userId and if it's there, check if it's the same data type that is stored in the DB.